# Why is a decent response to a poorly asked question getting downvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, down-votes

The question has been answered with a clear and valid answer (in my opinion), but so far the answer has a -3 rating.

The question was obviously poorly asked (it is non-generic, contains unnecessary information, and is not grammatically correct), but it was from a new user and I thought it still deserved an answer.

It'd be good to understand the reason for the downvotes, so that it can be improved. The reasons I can think that it may have been downvoted are:

- It's an unhelpful answer or lacks information.
- It shouldn't have been answered as the question was poorly asked or unclear.
- I should have edited the question in order to improve it before answering (I'll do this anyway).

The question and answer are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288500/design-a-jsp-page-which-will-search-like-google/49288565#49288565).

Comment: Reason two usually applies. People tend to think answering off topic questions encourages more of those. (Which I agree with)

Comment: tbh, You only really get away with that with particularly fantastic, in depth answers. That wasn't bad, but it wasn't good either.

Answer (score 7):

First posts are under more scrutiny. When a new user posts a poorly asked question, and then they get an answer, it **sets a precedent** that it's okay to ask "bad" questions.

Answering a poorly asked question makes it so the user doesn't need to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I have often found that the subsequent questions show no improvement, and the user is often surprised when the question is poorly reviewed, downvoted or closed.

So IMO, it's more about the question, than the answer, even if the answer may have been helpful. I don't downvote these answers, but instead suggest that the answerer reads [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)....

> **Not all questions can or should be answered**.. avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
> - ...solicit opinions rather than facts.
> - ...have already been asked and answered many times before.
> - ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.